# Class inside a class in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How can i call a class inside a class in Python? For example:

```
class POINT:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class CIRCLE:
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
```

I want to call POINT class in CIRCLE.
Thanks for answers.

Comment: What have you tried doing? Also you don't "call" a class

Comment: are you trying to make circle inherit from point ?

Comment: Ummm, `class CIRCLE(POINT): ...`?

Comment: Can you illustrate (even if it is wrong syntactically) what are you trying to do? *"I want to call POINT class in CIRCLE"* does not describe what you are trying to achieve in a language that is understandable to anyone with some knowledge in programming.

Comment: I think what he's saying is he wants to make an instance of class point in class circle

Comment: What i am saying is i don't want to define x and y coordinates of a circle again. I want to call the POINT class, so to create a circle class, i just need to add radius to it. Again when i want to create a LINE class, i need to call two POINT class to hold point 1 and point 2 or when i want to create QUADRANGLE class i just need to call four POINT class inside it not 8 variable and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Circle:
    def __init__(self, point, radius):
        self.point = point
        self.radius = radius

c = Circle(Point(2,3), 5)
```

That way, you'll have a [class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) `Circle` which in its constructor accepts a point (an instance of class `Point`) and a radius, producing and instance of `Circle`.

Comment: i wanted to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to define the circle's center position using the POINT class? If this is what you want, you throw away the self.x/self.y inside CIRCLE and do `self.center = POINT(x,y)`.